# Can you make a server that fowards data sent to it to another server, and logs the requests sent to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

I'm making an app that "emulates" a game client on a game. Is there a way to make a server that logs the requests sent to it, and forwards them to another server? (python)

If it helps then im using HOSTS file to redirect the game traffic to the game servers.

Comment: You could by sending a new request to the new server with the body and headers of the original request.

Comment: you can use python's http.client module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)

Comment: @2pichar i get error ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.